# What free hosting solution do you recommend for this use case?

Tags: web-hosting, free

I want to create a site that basically lets me:

1. Write tutorial articles with nice formatting.
2. Display flash videos for my viewers.

Any suggestions on a free solution? Something that would allow me to purchase a domain name and upgrade would be a plus.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can always use a free blogging service ([blogger](http://www.blogger.com/), [wordpress](http://wordpress.com/)) and use [youtube](http://www.youtube.com) to host your videos and embed them in the post.

Comment: Wordpress is the way to go. Allows you to migrate to a self-hosted solution very easily.

Answer (score 2):

[Posterous](http://posterous.com/) has caught on in recent years as a simple but elegant solution. It's easy to get content into it and they support a large variety of formats including Flash video.

Here is the [Posterous FAQ](http://posterous.com/faq/) page which answers many questions you might have, including verification that they support Flash video content:

http://posterous.com/faq/

You can also purchase a domain and use that in the future, which was another part of your question. There is a page on that describes [setting up custom domains on Posterous](http://posterous.com/help/custom_domain/) (and describes it quite well, I should say):

http://posterous.com/help/custom_domain/